# Fractional Knapsack

Tags: knapsack-problem

I need to implement fractional knapsack to solve this problem

Value($}     20   50   10   90  110   70   60

Weight(lb)    3    4    1    5    6    3    4

but I'm getting confusing in how fractional knapsack work , I understand how the  knapsack only work.
So , in my program when I enter for example  the weight limit = 7

it's gave me  143

can you help me to understand how fractional knapsack work.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. Sorted list in Descending order of Value / Weight is created.
2. in your case the list will be 20/3 =6.6 , 50/4=12.75, 10/1=10,90/5=18,110/6=18.3,70/3=23.3,60/4=15
3. Descending order : 23.3,18.3,18,15,12.5,10,6.6
4. Weight =7.
5. pick item 1 from Desc order list. its w=3 and 3 < 7 So Total value =0+70=70
6. pick item 2 , w=6 ; 3+6<7? No. (so take fraction of it )
   weight left=7-3=4.  Parts taken=4*(18.3)=73.2
   total value =70+73.2=143.2 =answer

Answer (score -1):

The first step is to understand that the fractional knapsack problem is a greedy algorithm and therefore fulfills the greedy choice property. The property states that the first choice will be in all optimal solutions, in this case, **item k** with the **max** **weight(k)/value(k)** will always be taken and as much of it as possible. After understanding this concept we can move forward with the algorithm.

> First Sort all the items in the backpack using weight(i)/value(i).
>  Then for each item in the sorted list from i=1 to n.
>
> > Take as much possible from item(i) until filled.

Note this does not work for the 0/1 knapsack problem.